# $_get[] Undefined index

Tags: php, get

**polling.php**

```
<?php
require 'mysql_connect.php';

$randnumber1 = $_GET['randnumber'];


echo "$randnumber1";

$result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from login_rocord where randnumber='$randnumber1'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if ($row['username'] != "")
    echo "true";
else
    echo "false";
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<script>
    function polling() {

        var xmlHttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlHttp.status == 200 && xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                var result = xmlHttp.responseText;
                if (result == 'true') {
                    window.location.href = 'welcome.php';
                }
            }
        }

        //var randnumber = document.getElementById("randnumber").value;
        randnumber = "12345687";
        ** xmlHttp.open("GET", "polling.php?randnumber=" + randnumber, true); **
                xmlHttp.send();
    }
    setInterval("polling()", 1000)

</script>
```

And the question is that

> Undefined index: randnumber in polling.php

on `$randnumber1 = $_GET['randnumber'];`
I don't understand that why it even can't `echo "$randnumber"`?
How could I get the `randnumber` by using `$_GET[]`?
Thankyou,I'm a newcomer.

Comment: You should totally read this too https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: try printing `$randnumber1 = $_GET['randnumber'];` before this line `print_r($_GET)`

Comment: Where / how are you seeing the error?

Comment: I tried your code and I was able to get my numbers in to the PHP and then alert out the `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

As a better practise you should always use syntax like below

```
$randNo = isset($_GET['randnumber'])?$_GET['randnumber']:"";
echo $randNo;
```

This will always prevent you from undefined errors and keeps telling you that you are getting values or not.

Comment: Thank you.I have test this.It can help avoid the warning.But the $randNo still return nothing?